# Virtualbox bridged networking doesn't show adapters

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox on windows 7 64-bit, with CentOS5.5 as the guest os. I try to setup a bridged networking connection, but when I select bridged adapter, I can't choose any networking adapter in the second list. It just says not selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if something went wrong during install.  VirtualBox has a couple of unsigned network drivers that need to go into place for full network support.  You did accept them all, right?  You don't have anything on your machine that would prevent unsigned drivers from installing do you?

Comment: I'm doing a CentOS 5.5 (x64) net install into a VM with bridged networking on my Windows 7 x64 host right now.  No problems setting it up, seems to be working fine.  Sounding more and more like you've got a broken VirtualBox install on your machine.

Comment: @brian I've installed them all, as a matter of fact, I've even reinstalled it to double check that i've selected the option for bridged networking. And I don't have anything on my machine that would prevent unsigned drivers from installing. I also noticed that this was also a bug in a previous release of virtualbox. Is it possible that the bug still isn't removed completely?

Comment: What version are you running?  I'm on VBox 4.0.4.

Comment: @brian If my installation is broken, how can I find out what's broken? As I said I've reinstalled it already (with a new download, I lost the installation file), so that means there is something else which is preventing virtualbox from installing

Comment: @brian Vbox 4.0.4 too;)

Comment: Interesting.  Well, it's still working really nice here on mine.  I guess I'd say go check with the VBox forums.  With the large concentration of users there, hopefully someone else has encountered your issue and found a way around it already!

Comment: @brian I already did, unfortunately people there didn't respond yet, while I posted my question there before I posted it here. Thanks for your help anyway;)